# What to do about these +1 comments

Tags: discussion, comments, data-explorer, comment-flags

I was looking for +1 comments from the Data explorer when I noticed that there were about 20 +1 comments from a single user for a query. I then added a condition to find +1 comments from that single user and this is what I stumbled upon - https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/168121/214573/

That's about 224 +1 comments if I limit the length to 18 chars, 341 if I limit it to 20 chars, 421 if 22 chars and so on. (About 12 of them are like `+1......................`)

I don't seem to have enough flag to report them all as not constructive. Hence posting here to know what moderators think.

*Edit*: Just wanted to add that the user has 85.4k rep.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166076/is-writing-1-1-in-a-comment-bad-manners and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87120/why-do-users-feel-the-need-to-notify-each-other-1-when-they-upvote-a-question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you just brought it to everyone's attention, but for future reference report one using a custom reason (i.e. flag the *post*) and advise the mod that there a bunch there.

If they are spread all over include a link to the Data Explorer query in your message.

Comment: That isn't too helpful... mods don't have that great of tools to mass-delete comments *from a specific user*. Actually, giving a mod a SEDE query is the best way, since they then have a mass-list of comment id's to delete.

Comment: @hichris123 Well, I admit I jumped to the conclusion that they were grouped under a single question. IN the even that they are spread about a link to the data SE query should go in the message.

Comment: Don't bother with the flag.  I already know about it.

Comment: I've already added a DE query which might help. But good to know that mods are aware of it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey So... you wouldn't mind me putting together mass lists of comments to delete, right? ;)

Comment: Hm?  You know what to do about those.  There might be a way for SE corporate to mass-delete these, but I'm not going to bother them with it right now; they have their hands full with the DDOS attacks.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The advice we've gotten is to put together mass lists and post on meta.. or give them to helpless mods. :P We (Undo, Manish & I) do kinda have some identified... want to help? :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't see something wrong with my comments here nor with its content, it is a funny and negligible amount in comparing with my (comments) activity here > 9k v.s. 230, can't see something annoying in my comments, then what they are for, am I miss something, have to take that as standard, please apologize me I'll quite ignore your mods attention ---> I'll (little bit) change those commens (under the radar)